# How to cast a generic type when parameters differ but are convertable?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a method parameter that takes `IDictionary<string,string>` but I would like to pass it an `IDictionary<string,JToken>` (Newtonsoft.Json).

The cast fails at runtime but since `JToken` provides both implicit and explicit conversion methods, I thought there might be a way to cast.

How can this cast be achieved?

```
class MyClass
{
    void Method(IDictionary<string,string> data) {}
}

...
IDictionary<string,JToken> record = ...;
MyClass cls = new MyClass();
cls.Method((IDictionary<string,string>)record);
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cant `Cast` from one to the other, pretty much the only way is to create a new Dictionary:

```
IDictionary<string,JToken> record = ...;
MyClass cls = new MyClass();
cls.Method(record.ToDictionary(k => k.Key,v => (string)v.Value));
```